# Incorrect serialization with symfony serializer

Tags: symfony, serialization

I am trying to serialize my Entity to json using symfony/serializer.
I want to get something like

```
  {
    "id" : "string",
    "name" : "name here",
    "admin": "admin_id"
  }
```

But I always end up with complete tree - resulting json contains all related entities with their relationships. I believe that it must be trivial task with symfony/serializer and obviously doing something wrong, but what?

CarbonNormalizer simply returns string representation of nesbot/carbon object.

Here is my controller:

```
    $data=$this->em->getRepository('Cpa:Cpa')->findAll();
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();//object -same
    $dateTimeNormalizer = new CarbonNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });
    $this->serializer = new Serializer([$dateTimeNormalizer, $normalizer], [$encoder]);

    $data = $this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json', ['groups' => ['show'], 'enable_max_depth' => true]);
    return new JsonResponse($data, $code, [], true);
```

And my entity:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Cpa\Models;


use Domain\Offer\Models\CpaOffer;
use Domain\User\Models\User;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

class Cpa
{
/** @var  string */
private $id;

/** @var  string */
private $name;

/** @var  User */
private $admin;

/** @var  CpaOffer[] */
private $offers;

/**
 * Cpa constructor.
 * @param string $name
 * @param User $admin
 */
public function __construct($name, User $admin)
{
    $this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->admin = $admin;
    $this->offers = [];
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getId(): string
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName(): string
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getAdmin(): User
{
    return $this->admin;
}

/**
 * @return CpaOffer[]
 */
public function getOffers()//: array
{
    return $this->offers;
}
```

}

serialization.yml

```
Domain\Cpa\Models\Cpa:
 attributes:
   id:
    groups: ['show']
   name:
    groups: ['show']
   admin:
    groups: ['show']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use groups, you need to initialize the `ClassMetadataFactory` too:

```
// Don't forget to add the new use statements
// ...
$normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer(
  new ClassMetadataFactory(
    new YamlFileLoader('/the/path/to/yourfile.yaml')
  )
);
// ...
```

You must also fix the indentation of your YAML file:

```
'Domain\Cpa\Models\Cpa':
  attributes:
    id:
      groups: ['show']
    name:
      groups: ['show']
    admin:
      groups: ['show']
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Is there a way to inject configured serializer into my service/controller? 

'/the/path/to/yourfile.yaml' - is it path to serialization.yml?